# getting SQLSTATE[42000] error when i try to fill a dynamic dropdown

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I'm trying to fill 3 dynamic drop-down menus to filter images from a catalog.

I need to filter them by emotion(emocion in Spanish within my code) which they are only 3 happiness, anger and sadness(alegria, ira, tristeza)each of those categories can have 3 levels of intensity like high, medium and low (Alto, medio, bajo).

So then for example when you select `anger+level of activation`(it has to be only in that order, meaning emotion should be first always) it should fill the third `drop-down` with images of those specifications.

My table  `Emocion`  in my data base has only 2 columns `id` and `emocion` and has the 3 emotions registered.

I tried adding this line `Schema::defaultStringLength(191);`on `app/Providers/AppServiceProvider.php`but it wont work and i tried
in `config\database.php` -->   `"mysql"`array 
Set `'strict' => false` to disable all.

For now im just trying to fill the first drop-down from my database.

Here is the code of my controller:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Admin;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\User;
use DB;
class PlantillaImagenesController extends Controller{

    public function index()
    {
            $emocion_list =  DB:: table('Emocion')
                                ->groupBy('Emocion')
                                ->get();
             return view ('admin.Imagen.index')->with('users', User::all())->with('emocion_list', $emocion_list);
    } 

}
```

And here is my first 2 drop-downs :

```
<div class="input-group mb-3">
    <div class="input-group-prepend">
        <label class="input-group-text" for="inputGroupSelect01">Emocion</label>
    </div>
    <select name="emocion"class="custom-select input-lg dynamic"  id="emocion" data-dependent = "intensidad">                                                    
        <option value="">Selecciona Emocion</option>
        @foreach ($emocion_list as $emocion )
            <option value="{{ $emocion->emocion }}">{{$emocion->emocion }}</option>
        @endforeach
    </select>
    </div>



    <div class="input-group mb-3">
    <div class="input-group-prepend">
        <label class="input-group-text" for="inputGroupSelect01">Intensidad</label>
    </div>
    <select name="intensidad" class="custom-select" id="intensidad" data-dependent = "imagen">                                                    

    </select>
    </div>
```

and my route file :

```
Auth::routes();


Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');

Route::namespace('Admin')->prefix('admin')->middleware(['auth',  'auth.admin'])->name('admin.')->group(function(){
    Route::resource('/ImagenAudioVideo',  'PlantillaController', ['except' => ['show', 'create', 'store'] ]);
    Route::get('/Imagen',  'PlantillaImagenesController@index'); // <-------------------------->this one
    Route::resource('/Audio',  'PlantillaAudiosController', ['except' => ['show', 'create', 'store'] ]);
    Route::resource('/Video',  'PlantillaVideosController', ['except' => ['show', 'create', 'store'] ]);
    Route::resource('/ImagenAudio',  'PlantillaImagenesAudioController', ['except' => ['show', 'create', 'store'] ]);
    Route::resource('/EditarUsuario',  'EditarUsuariosController', ['except' => ['show', 'create', 'store'] ]);
    Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('home');
});

});
```

im getting this error:

> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1055 Expression #1 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'configiem.Emocion.IdEmocion' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by (SQL: select * from `Emocion` group by `Emocion`)

Comment: You have mistake in your code query for groupings, anyway you can posts your table as well.

Comment: This comment doesn't solve anything

Comment: Yes because your question is broad at the moment, so you have to post the other things.

Comment: like what things? i explained what i have on my table and what code im using for this function of my page

Comment: @RicardoWallace try `set global sql_mode='STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION';` in your DB

Comment: @MeeraTank now it show this error : ```Route [admin.Imagen.index] not defined. (View: /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/ConfiguradorIEM/resources/views/home.blade.php)```

Comment: @RicardoWallace did you write `{{ route('...')}}` in your blade file? mistake is in route name, please check for same

Comment: Yeah it is correct because the error comes from a button in the view before this, the button just goes to the view where im working, that view worked properly before this. i think it has something to do with my resource/get controller, when i first created the controller i made it with resource and then i changed to get.

Answer (score 0):

Your mistake is on this code

```
 $emocion_list =  DB:: table('Emocion')
                           ->groupBy('Emocion')
                           ->get();
```

You have to defile on `select()` other columns this have not use in `groupBy()` or aggregate function.

Write this I think it will work

```
 $emocion_list =  DB:: table('Emocion')
                           ->select('emocion')
                           ->groupBy('emocion')
                           ->get();
```

Comment: provide us your DB table structure

Comment: table name: ```Emocion``` and the colummns : ```IdEmocion``` and ```emocion```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
 $emocion_list =  DB::table('Emocion')
                       ->select('emocion')
                       ->groupBy('emocion')
                       ->get();
```

If you are using Eloquent ORM,

```
 $emocion_list =  Emicon::select('emocion')
                       ->groupBy('emocion')
                       ->get();
```